# Rustのメモリ解放に関してOptionにNoneを設定するだけで問題無いでしょうか？

Tags: rust

libraryとして外部から利用する事を想定しています。
global領域にstart/stopにてメモリの確保と破棄を行うケースがあると思いますが、
rustではOptionにNoneを設定するだけで問題無いのでしょうか？

下記がC言語のケース
c code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {}DATA;
static DATA* gData = NULL;

void start(){
    if(gData == NULL) gData = (DATA*)malloc(sizeof(DATA));
}
void stop() {
    free(gData);
    data = NULL;
}
```

Rustによるケース
rust code

```
struct DATA {}

static mut RUSTDATA : Option<DATA> = None;
#[no_mangle]
fn start(){
    unsafe{
        RUSTDATA = Some(DATA{});
    }
}
#[no_mangle]
fn stop(){
    unsafe{
        RUSTDATA = None;
    }
}
```

Comment: どういう状態が確認できたら「問題無い」といえるのかが質問から読みとれず、回答のしようがないです。逆にどのような問題があることを心配されているのか教えてもらえませんか？　例：プログラムがクラッシュしそう

Comment: あるいは質問を変えて、このRustコードはこのCコードと等価ですか？　にしてもらえると回答しやすいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> rustではOptionにNoneを設定するだけで問題無いのでしょうか？

`stop`関数で`None`を代入した時に`start`関数で代入したオブジェクトは破棄されるので問題ありません。

例えば`Drop` traitを実装すると確認できます

```rust
struct DATA {}

impl Drop for DATA {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropped!")
    }
}

static mut RUSTDATA: Option<DATA> = None;

#[no_mangle]
fn start() {
    unsafe {
        RUSTDATA = Some(DATA {});
    }
}
#[no_mangle]
fn stop() {
    unsafe {
        RUSTDATA = None;
    }
}

fn main() {
    start();
    stop();
    println!("End main thread");
}
```

```
$ cargo run
Dropped!
End main thread
```

なおグローバル変数に書き込むのは複数のスレッドから書き込む場合に危険なのでunsafeになっています。このような場合にはMutexを使って排他制御を行うのが通例です。

参考: [Rustのstatic変数とthread local](https://qiita.com/tatsuya6502/items/bed3702517b36afbdbca)